# What steps can I take to resolve version conflict errors when using Flutter packages with pub get?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

When i'm typing to do pub get in flutter i'm getting some errors

```
`**Resolving dependencies...
Because every version of month_year_picker depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.18.1, every version of month_year_picker requires intl 0.18.1.
So, because assingment depends on both intl ^0.17.0 and month_year_picker ^0.2.0+3, version solving failed.**`
```

```
**Because month_year_picker <0.3.0+1 depends on intl ^0.17.0 and assingment depends on intl ^0.18.1, month_year_picker <0.3.0+1 is forbidden.
So, because assingment depends on month_year_picker ^0.2.0+3, version solving failed.**
```

I have tried degrading and upgrading intl package but still it shows errors and i'm not able to use pub get in android Studio

Comment: Remove one of the conflicted packages then pub get, and install that package using command : `flutter pub add <packagename>`

Comment: Thankyou Shanu , I was able to remove all error by running command #flutter downgrade

Answer (score 0):

Remove one of the conflicted packages then pub get, and install that package using command : `flutter pub add <packagename>`

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this to your pubspec.

```
dependencies:
  assingment:
    dependency_overrides:
      month_year_picker: ^0.3.0+1
```

2. Run `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any` instead of a specific package version, however, it is not recommended especially when you want to release the app.

```yaml
dependencies:
  ...
  some_dependency: any
  ...
```

In addition, [Version Lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pflannery.vscode-versionlens) is a useful extension in this case.